# What is the centralizer of a Coxeter element?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, coxeter-groups

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter system (of finite rank) and $c \in W$ a Coxeter element.

If $W$ is finite, then the centralizer $C_W(c)$ is the cyclic group generated by $c$ (e.g. see the book "Reflection Groups and Invariant Theory" of Kane).

If $(W,S)$ is irreducible and not finite or affine, then the cyclic group $\langle c \rangle$ is of finite index in $C_W(c)$ (see Theorem 2.6 in the paper "Irreducible Coxeter Groups" by Luis Paris).

Are there more results in this direction? For affine Coxeter groups? Is it conjectured that $C_W(c) = \langle c \rangle$ holds in general? Or is there a counterexample?

**Update**: There is a paper called "On the centralizer of a Coxeter element" by Blokhina (seems like that he/ she was a student of Vinberg), originally in russian, but there is an english translation in Moscow Univ. Math. Bull. You find an entry 
[here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Blokhina&s5=Centralizers&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)
on mathscinet.

I just managed to get a copy of that paper (but because of the copyright I'm not sure if I'm allowed to make it available here). The following statement is proven in that paper (including all infinite affine families David is mentioning in his comment):

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter system of finite rank and $c \in W$ a Coxeter element. If $(W,S)$ is of type $\widetilde{A}_n$ or if the Coxeter graph of $(W,S)$ is a tree **and** all of its labels are 3 (that is, it is simply-laced), then $C_W(c)= \langle c \rangle$.

(The arguments in the proof are somewhat similar to the proof of the statement for finite Coxeter groups given by Carter. Jim mentioned this reference implicitely in his comment. I add it here: It is Proposition 30 in Carter's paper "Conjugacy Classes in the Weyl group".)

Comment: Have you tried to exhibit Coxeter elements in explicit affine Coxeter groups, such as type $\widetilde{A_n}$?

Comment: Do you mean "Irreducible Coxeter Groups" by Luis Paris ? That has a relevant Theorem 2.6.

Comment: Yes, thanks! The author is L. Paris (I edited it in my question).

Comment: I haven't explicitely tried any affine type so far. But apperentely there is a paper "Centralizer of a Coxeter element" (in russian) by Blokhina (Moscow University Mathematics Bulletin 44(3)) in whose abstract it is claimed that the problem is solved for Coxeter Systems whose Coxeter graph is a tree as well as for affine type $\widetilde{A}_n$.

Comment: Other references for the case of a finite Coxeter group are given in my unpublished notes   http://people.math.umass.edu/~jeh/pub/count.pdf, but I'm unsure about infinite Coxeter groups.

Comment: I have a case by case check that $C_W(c) = \langle c \rangle$ in types $\tilde{A}$, $\tilde{B}$, $\tilde{C}$ and $\tilde{D}$, which I'll post if nobody posts something better. (Sorry for deleting then reposting this comment; I thought I found an error in my type $\tilde{D}$ work, but it was right the first time.)

Comment: Thanks for checking the affine cases! I edited my post and gave a reference which includes these cases.

Comment: It's helpful to define first what is meant by 'Coxeter element'. starting with  fimite and the Coxeter graph being a tree (as in most affine cases); this makes $c$ well-defined up to conjugacy.    See for example the set-up in https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0424967

Comment: Blokhina relies on an article of Subbotin and Stekolshchik:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01077574
where they treat the statement "the Coxeter graph is a tree" in a more restrictive sense, requiring in addition that all labels $m_{st}$ equal 3. This can be seen from the second paragraph of their article, where they notice that the value of the bilinear form on any pair of simple roots is either 0 or -1/2. Thus, Blokhina's result refers only to those Coxeter systems whose graph is a tree AND all labels $m_{st}$ are equal to 3.

Comment: Thanks. I will correct my post.